# Good LaTeX template for book about Quran

Tags: xetex, document-classes, polyglossia, books

As I want to write a  "book" about Al-Quran which looks good and furthermore can handle Para number, Surah number,  Ayat number, Ruku number etc. by layouting them as good as possible. Can anyone suggest or even provide a good template which satisfies my needs?

Here is the format which I need:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\title{Book Title}
\date{\today}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
 
\section{Surah 1}
\section{Surah 2}
\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

*Note:* The design may not be exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried to see how close you can get to your desired output with the `quran` package?

Comment: @ Thérèse Actually I am new in Latex. I have no much idea about it

Comment: The `quran` package has a nice manual. By the way, since you’re compiling with `xetex`, you don’t need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @ Thérèse Can you illustrate this with an example?

Comment: There are three test files in the documentation directory of the `quran` package.